# pixel value not obeyed

Tags: html, css

My resolution is 1920x1080, and when I hardcode a width value in pixels for a div, in the below example to 200px, it actually shows up as 250px on my screen when I take a screenshot and measure it in photoshop.
My friend, who is on a 4k screen, did the same and it was 450px wide.

I understand it will be different if I set the value in percent, but this is pixel. shouldnt it be the same regardless of screen?

this example is table and table-cell, but I had the exact same problem with flexbox, when setting a hardcoded pixel value on the width for a menu bar.

what is it that im not understanding?

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}




.main{
    display: table;
}



.a{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
        <div class="a">
            width set to 200px
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **CSS pixels are not device pixels**, and thank god they designed it this way! OS scaling also takes effect here. Your photoshop is measuring device/OS screen pixels. https://elad.medium.com/understanding-the-difference-between-css-resolution-and-device-resolution-28acae23da0b

Comment: your way of measuring pixel is wrong, you should instead use Right click > Inspect Element.

Comment: thanks to both of you. this actually make sense. i was just worried i was doing something wrong.